# Creating a mobile VSliderSkin for VSlider - with test case and screenshots

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile, flex4.7

[HSlider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/HSlider.html) has been optimized for mobile, but [VSlider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VSlider.html) not - as you can see here:

[image]

At the same time the mobile-themed [HSliderSkin.as](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/mobiletheme/src/spark/skins/mobile/HSliderSkin.as) looks pretty simple.

So I've copied that file to a "VSliderSkin.as" in my very simple test project and -

1. replaced the obvious references to "HSlider" by "VSlider"
2. in the measure() method swapped "width" <-> "height"
3. in the layoutContents() swapped "width" <-> "height" and "x" <-> "y"

**SlideApp.mxml** (just add to a blank Flex mobile project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    applicationDPI="160">

    <s:VSlider
        skinClass="VSliderSkin"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        height="80%" />

    <s:HSlider
        skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.HSliderSkin"
        width="100%"
        bottom="10" />

</s:Application>
```

**VSliderSkin.as** (put into the same dir as the SlideApp.as):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
//  Copyright 2010 Adobe Systems Incorporated
//  All Rights Reserved.
//
//  NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
//  in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package {
    import flash.display.BlendMode;

    import mx.core.ClassFactory;
    import mx.core.IFactory;

    import spark.components.Button;
    import spark.components.VSlider;
    import spark.skins.mobile.HSliderThumbSkin;
    import spark.skins.mobile.HSliderTrackSkin;
    import spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses.HSliderDataTip;
    import spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses.MobileSkin;

    /**
     *  ActionScript-based skin for VSlider controls in mobile applications.
     * 
     *  <p>The base Flex implementation creates an VSlider with fixed height
     *  and variable width with a fixed-size thumb. As the height of the
     *  VSlider component increases, the vertical dimensions of the visible VSlider remain
     *  the same, and the VSlider stays vertically centered.</p>
     * 
     *  <p>The thumb and track implementations can be customized by subclassing
     *  this skin class and overriding the thumbSkinClass, trackSkinClass,
     *  and/or dataTipClass variables as necessary.</p>
     * 
     *  @langversion 3.0
     *  @playerversion Flash 10
     *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
     *  @productversion Flex 4.5
     */
    public class VSliderSkin extends MobileSkin
    {    
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Constructor
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         * 
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5
         * 
         */    
        public function VSliderSkin()
        {
            super();

            thumbSkinClass = HSliderThumbSkin;
            trackSkinClass = HSliderTrackSkin;
            dataTipClass = spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses.HSliderDataTip;

            blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Properties
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /** 
         *  @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        public var hostComponent:VSlider;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Skin parts 
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         *  VSlider track skin part
         *
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5
         */    
        public var track:Button;

        /**
         *  VSlider thumb skin part
         * 
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5
         */    
        public var thumb:Button;

        /**
         *  VSlider dataTip class factory
         * 
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5
         */    
        public var dataTip:IFactory;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Variables
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         *  Specifies the skin class that will be used for the VSlider thumb.
         * 
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5 
         */    
        protected var thumbSkinClass:Class;

        /**
         *  Specifies the skin class that will be used for the VSlider track.
         * 
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5 
         */    
        protected var trackSkinClass:Class;

        /**
         *  Specifies the class that will be used for the VSlider datatip.
         * 
         *  @langversion 3.0
         *  @playerversion Flash 10
         *  @playerversion AIR 2.5 
         *  @productversion Flex 4.5 
         */    
        protected var dataTipClass:Class;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Overridden methods
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         *  @private 
         */ 
        override protected function commitCurrentState():void
        {
            if (currentState == "disabled")
                alpha = 0.5;
            else if (currentState == "normal")
                alpha = 1;
        }    

        /**
         *  @private 
         */ 
        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            // Create our skin parts: track and thumb
            track = new Button();
            track.setStyle("skinClass", trackSkinClass);
            addChild(track);

            thumb = new Button();
            thumb.setStyle("skinClass", thumbSkinClass);
            addChild(thumb);

            // Set up the class factory for the dataTip
            dataTip = new ClassFactory();
            ClassFactory(dataTip).generator = dataTipClass;
        }

        /**
         *  @private 
         *  The HSliderSkin width will be no less than the width of the thumb skin.
         *  The HSliderSkin height will be no less than the greater of the heights of
         *  the thumb and track skins.
         */ 
        override protected function measure():void
        {
            measuredHeight = track.getPreferredBoundsHeight();
            measuredWidth = Math.max(track.getPreferredBoundsWidth(), thumb.getPreferredBoundsWidth());

            measuredMinWidth = Math.max(track.getPreferredBoundsWidth(), thumb.getPreferredBoundsWidth());
            measuredMinHeight = thumb.getPreferredBoundsHeight();
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */ 
        override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.layoutContents(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            // minimum height is no smaller than the larger of the thumb or track
            var calculatedSkinWidth:int = Math.max(Math.max(thumb.getPreferredBoundsWidth(), track.getPreferredBoundsWidth()),
                unscaledWidth);

            // minimum width is no smaller than the thumb
            var calculatedSkinHeight:int = Math.max(thumb.getPreferredBoundsHeight(),
                unscaledHeight);

            // once we know the skin height, center the thumb and track
            thumb.x = Math.max(Math.round((calculatedSkinWidth - thumb.getPreferredBoundsWidth()) / 2), 0);
            var calculatedTrackX:int = Math.max(Math.round((calculatedSkinWidth - track.getPreferredBoundsWidth()) / 2), 0);

            // size and position
            setElementSize(thumb, thumb.getPreferredBoundsWidth(), thumb.getPreferredBoundsHeight()); // thumb does NOT scale
            setElementSize(track, track.getPreferredBoundsWidth(), calculatedSkinHeight);
            setElementPosition(track, calculatedTrackX, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that didn't work, but is very close and the thumb moves vertically - as it should:

[image]

Does anybody please have an idea how to complete my mobile skin?

Should I create a copy of the [HSliderTrackSkin.as](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/mobiletheme/src/spark/skins/mobile/HSliderTrackSkin.as) too? Or maybe the non-mobile [VSliderTrackSkin.mxml](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/skins/spark/VSliderTrackSkin.mxml) can be (ab)used here?

Comment: Ideally, you would create your own VSliderTrackSkin that is based off of the mobile HSliderTrackSkin. Two good reasons for doing this: 1) the mobile version is done in AS3, which is much more optimal for mobile devices than an MXML based skin, 2) the mobile skin has 3 separate FXG assets for the track that it can use based on the device's DPI, while the MXML skin uses Spark primitive graphics objects to draw the track. Both of these concepts will make the device use less CPU while rendering, and give the slider track the same appearance as in the HSlider.

Comment: If your app only had one VSlider in it, I would not worry about performance issues as they are probably minor. However, the visual appearance of the VSlider is more of an issue for me. As you noticed, the track is smaller in the non-mobile case, and that will surely look different on devices that have different DPI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you own class like a CustomVSlider and put inside HSlider with changed rotation(**rotation = 90**). It's work great for me. Hope this help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
applicationDPI="160">

<s:HSlider
    skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.HSliderSkin"
    height="100%" left="50"
    top="100" rotation="90"/>

<s:HSlider
    skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.HSliderSkin"
    width="100%"
    top="300" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks! using Spark HSliderTrackSkin has worked for me too, but your solution is simple and effective